# Difficulties with managing List items

Tags: c#, .net, list, xna

I don't really know how this stuff happens in internal memory / processor.

I've created a class named `Block` that has a *position*. Also I have a `List<Block>` to store my blocks.

First, I add a Block to that list:

```
blocks.Add(new Block());
```

Then, I want to clone that block, so that I have two independent blocks with different positions in my list:

```
Block clonedBlock = blocks[0];
blocks.Add(clonedBlock);
```

But when I change the position of the newly created block, I also change the one of the first one.

Why does it do that and is there any way to prevent that?

And by the way, I've noticed that Lists seem to have a few strange behaviors. 
For example in this case:

```
List<Block> list01 = new List<Block>();
[... add some blocks to that list ...]
List<Block> list02 = list01; // also tried: List<Block> list02 = list01.ToList();
[... change item in list01 ...] --> also changes that item in list02
```

This made me guess that Lists only contain something like pointer and when I try to "clone" a block, I only copy the pointer, but the position its pointing to stays the same. Same question: is there any way to prevent that?

**Edit: Solution: [Object.MemberwiseClone()- Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)**

Comment: Your guess is essentially correct.  Classes are reference types, so your line `Block clonedBlock = blocks[0];` is setting the `clonedBlock` to the same address as `blocks[0]`.  Any changes made to one will be reflected in the other.  You're better off to create a new instance of `Block` and add it to the list, unless there's some reason you want to copy the other block and simply change it's position?

Comment: Another way to handle this is to implement a deep copy (I think that's the term - been years since I did anything in C++).  Create a new instance of `Block`, and then copy the values from the original to the new one.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!
It would be possible to just create a new instance of Block, but this would not be a good solution because my List doesn't really store blocks of the type Block, but blocks of child classes of Block, so I would first need to figure out, which child class it and so on... :/ 

Is there really no way to just "clone" / "copy" a block?

Comment: Not that I can think of off the top of my head (which in no way means there isn't).  You could look at implementing `ICloneable`, or simply writing your own copy method.   You might want to post a new question (or change your title) dealing with how to deep copy or clone objects - that's likely to get you more views and answers.  Posting some sample code so we can see the objects you're working with would help as well.

Comment: Also, take a look at the [Object.MemberwiseClone Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) - it has an example of doing both a shallow and deep copy.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for you help!! It really helped me a lot. If I had figured out how to rate answers, I'd some sort of 'award' you, but unfortunately I haven't yet..

Comment: You can rate comments (though I don't remember how much rep you need to do so).  I can post an answer below if you like, but you had already figured out what the issue was - I just confirmed it for you :)

Comment: haha yeah, then post an answer below to get at least a tiny reward for your effort.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is essentially correct. Classes are reference types, so your line Block clonedBlock = blocks[0]; is setting the clonedBlock to the same address as blocks[0]. Any changes made to one will be reflected in the other. You're better off to create a new instance of Block and add it to the list, unless there's some reason you want to copy the other block and simply change it's position.

One way to hanlde this is to implement a deep copy (I think that's the term - been years since I did anything in C++). Create a new instance of Block, and then copy the values from the original to the new one.

You could look at implementing ICloneable, or simply writing your own copy method (in reality if you implement ICloneable, you're still writing your own copy method - the interface just ensures that classes using it implement a `Clone` method.  Deep or shallow is up to the implementer).

Also, take a look at the [Object.MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) Method.  `Object.MemberwiseClone` does a shallow copy, but there is an example of doing both a shallow and deep copy in Examples section.

Comment: Thanks again, Object.MemberwiseClone()- Method was exactly what I was looking for! :)